# Cannot ping Wireless IP when ethernet is connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, ping

I have a computer with a USB-to-WiFi adapter and and Ethernet port.

When I connect the PC to the wireless network I receive an IP and I'm able to ping it.
However when I connect the Ethernet cable as well I'm not able to ping the IP of the wireless adapter any more.

What could be the problem?

Comment: both wireless and wired network is in same subnet with same gateway?

Comment: @Kaveh yes they are

Comment: IS it right? after plugged in Ethernet cable, you cannot ping your own USB wifi?

Comment: @Kaveh I can ping the IP of the wifi adapter untill I plug in the ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an IP conflict since both ports are on the same segment. Then, you need to define what interface you use, using the "route" command.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you use Windows. Probably the firewall doesn't allow ping. Try to disable the firewall to check it.